# What is the difference between the xpath //*[.="Foo"] and the xpath //*["Foo"] with only a string in the predicate?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Doing some testing in iPython with a new (to me) way of selecting nodes based on their text in an xpath. (Irrelevant lines omitted for clarity)

```
In [26]: from lxml import etree

In [41]: string = '''
    ...: <outer>
    ...:    <mid>
    ...:       <inner>Foo</inner>
    ...:    </mid>
    ...: </outer>
    ...: '''

In [43]: root = etree.fromstring(string)

In [44]: root.xpath('//inner[text()="Foo"]')
Out[44]: [<Element inner at 0x10a0387c0>]

In [45]: root.xpath('//inner[.="Foo"]')
Out[45]: [<Element inner at 0x10a0387c0>]

In [47]: root.xpath('//inner["Foo"]')
Out[47]: [<Element inner at 0x10a0387c0>]
```

That all makes sense to me so far. However:

```
In [48]: root.xpath('//*[text()="Foo"]')
Out[48]: [<Element inner at 0x10a0387c0>]

In [49]: root.xpath('//*[.="Foo"]')
Out[49]: [<Element inner at 0x10a0387c0>]

In [50]: root.xpath('//*["Foo"]')
Out[50]: 
[<Element outer at 0x10a188200>,
 <Element mid at 0x10a01d6c0>,
 <Element inner at 0x10a0387c0>]
```

I had expected the second and third xpaths to produce the same result by matching all three nodes. Can anyone explain why they're different?

Comment: The text of `outer` and `mid` has whitespace around `Foo`, so they don't match it exactly.

Comment: In that case, I'm unclear on what `//*["Foo"]` is actually selecting, since I would expect that to account for the whitespace too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) says

> A PredicateExpr is evaluated by evaluating the Expr and converting the result to a boolean. If the result is a number, the result will be converted to true if the number is equal to the context position and will be converted to false otherwise; *if the result is not a number, then the result will be converted as if by a call to the boolean function*. Thus a location path `para[3]` is equivalent to `para[position()=3]`.

(emphasis mine). Thus

```
root.xpath('//*["Foo"]')
```

is equivalent to

```
root.xpath('//*["Lemon Pie"]')
```

It does not test for content of your `<inner>` node; in fact, because `"Foo"` is a truthy literal, AFAIK it is also equivalent to

```
root.xpath('//*')
```

As Barmar said, the first and second expression do not match nodes other than `<inner>` because of whitespace. To get all three, trim (or "normalize space", in XPath language):

```
root.xpath('//*[normalize-space()="Foo"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Amadan's answer, your first and second expressions are not equivalent. Both of them will match

```
<Inner>Foo</Inner>
```

but they give different results for constructs such as

```
<Inner><span>Foo</span></Inner>
```

or

```
<Inner>Foo<nbsp/>Bar</Inner>
```

As a general rule, 9 times out of 10 when someone uses `text()` they should change it to `.`.